comparing two measures on the square
Let $\lambda _d$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $R^d$. Let $\mu$ be a measure on Borel subsets of $[0,1]^2$ such that $\mu <<\lambda _2$ and $\mu (B\times [0,1])=\mu ([0,1]\times B)=\lambda _1 (B)$ for every Borel $B\subseteq [0,1]$. Does it necessarily hold that $\mu (D)=\lambda _2 (D)$ for every Borel $D\subseteq [0,1]^2$?

I asked the same question and got a good answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4673085/is-this-measure-the-lebesgue-measure-on-0-12

Consider the measure with probability density
$$
f = 2\cdot (1_{[0,1/2]^2}+1_{[1/2,1]^2}).
$$
